# How does express.js catch ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

```js
// Sample code
app.get("/test", (res, res) => {
   return res.status(200).send(SOME_UNDEFINED_VAR);
});
```

In case of ReferenceError, express.js sends 500 by default.

> express.js writes the **ReferenceError** on std out but i want to write such error on a file using my logger.

tried using

```js
app.use((err, res, res) => {
    logger.error(err) // this handler is not getting called
    // this handler is only for `next(err)`
})
```

I know reference errors can be caught by linting tools and this case will never come but I still want to know how to catch such error.

Comment: wrap your code with try catch block

Comment: I have a exiting huge code base

Comment: try catch is only way to handle ReferenceError. if you want to identify the Reference error you can use
try {
console.log(x)
} catch(e) {
console.log(e instanceof ReferenceError) // true
}

Comment: when you will run your project in production you can use pm2 for example that will store the normal output in out.log file and error output in err.log file

Comment: but how does express captures it, is there is any way to override?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same problem.

My solution to catch references error with expressjs Error handler was to use the try and catch block inside route function and then use next(err) in the catch block. You'll have to check if the error is really a references error though.